# Flutter - Text foreground is not showing up on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, border, skia, flutter-custompainter

I'm trying to create a text with a border. I've written this code

```dart
LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (_, constraints) => Container(
        width: constraints.maxHeight,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(width: 1),
          color: Colors.yellow,
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(
                'HI',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: scaleAdapter(50),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  foreground: Paint()
                    ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
                    ..color = Colors.red
                    ..strokeWidth = 5,
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                'HI',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: scaleAdapter(50),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

But I only see the black text. The red one is completely covered by the black one in the stack (see picture).

[image: iOS is not working]
[image: Android works]

Platform is iOS (left image). Android (right image) is working fine.
I suspect it is something involving Impeller (since Android AFAIK is still using SKIA), but I'm definitely not sure...

My `flutter doctor -v` output:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.5, on macOS 13.3.1 22E772610a darwin-arm64, locale it-IT)
    • Flutter version 3.10.5 on channel stable at /Applications/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 796c8ef792 (3 weeks ago), 2023-06-13 15:51:02 -0700
    • Engine revision 45f6e00911
    • Dart version 3.0.5
    • DevTools version 2.23.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/alessandrodefendenti/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Users/alessandrodefendenti/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/222.4459.24.2221.10121639/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14E300c
    • CocoaPods version 1.12.0

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
    • Android Studio at /Users/alessandrodefendenti/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/222.4459.24.2221.10121639/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
    • Android Studio at /Users/alessandrodefendenti/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/222.4459.24.2221.9971841/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2023.1.3)
    • IntelliJ at /Users/alessandrodefendenti/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-C/ch-0/231.9161.38/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2023.1.2)
    • IntelliJ at /Users/alessandrodefendenti/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-C/ch-0/231.9011.34/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

[✓] VS Code (version 1.79.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.68.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-arm64   • macOS 13.3.1 22E772610a darwin-arm64
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 114.0.5735.198

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered that actually this is a known Impeller issue. It's being tracked here:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/126010

In order to make it work we can temporarily disable Impeller on iOS (using old but gold Skia)

https://docs.flutter.dev/perf/impeller#ios

Closing

**EDIT October 06th, 2023**
This has been fixed and now Impeller works nicely

Comment: I am having the same issue, how can i fix this?

Comment: if you install the latest version of the stable branch it should be fixed. However if it is not, you can run the app with skia by passing the `--no-enable-impeller` after the `flutter run` command