# Transparent Text with border flutter

Tags: ios, flutter

in flutter 3.7.12 I achieved this text style:

[image]

with this code:

```dart
Text(
  'ZA DARMO',
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 50,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
    background: Paint()..color = Colors.transparent,
    foreground: Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 0.1
      ..color = Colors.white,
  ),
),
```

(It creates text that have a white stroke but have transparent body (you can see gradient behind it))

But in the latest version of flutter 3.10.6 it doesn't work. Instead, it creates filled white text. Does anyone know a solution how to achieve this now?

> I have found out that on Android devices it still works, but does not work on iOS

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76619307/flutter-text-foreground-is-not-showing-up-on-ios